# Passing named arguments as array in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have this code in a tool I am currently building:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    --var1=*)
      var1="${1#*=}"
      ;;
    --var2=*)
      var1="${1#*=}"
      ;;
    --var3=*)
      var1="${1#*=}"
      ;;
    *)
      printf "***************************\n
              * Error: Invalid argument.*\n
              ***************************\n"
  esac
  shift
done
```

I have many options to add, but five of my options should be saved as arrays. So if I call the tool, let's say from the shell using something like this:
`./tool --var1="2" --var1="3" --var1="4" --var1="5" --var2="6" --var3="7"`

How can I save the value of `var1` as an array? Is that possible? And, if so, what is the best way to deal with these arrays in terms of efficiency if I have too many of them?.

Comment: May be better to use [getopts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial)

Comment: @fedorqui, `bash`'s `getopts` doesn't support long options. Only `ksh93`'s one does. See also [this `getopts_long`](https://github.com/stephane-chazelas/misc-scripts/blob/master/getopts_long.sh)

Comment: is this what you need? : [Specify command line arguments like name=value pairs for shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43008569/3957754)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If on Linux (with the `util-linux` utilities including `getopt` installed, or the one from `busybox`), you can do:

```
declare -A opt_spec
var1=() var2=() var4=false
unset var3
opt_spec=(
  [opt1:]='var1()' # opt with argument, array variable
  [opt2:]='var2()' # ditto
  [opt3:]='var3'   # opt with argument, scalar variable
  [opt4]='var4'    # boolean opt without argument
)
parsed_opts=$(
  IFS=,
  getopt -o + -l "${!opt_spec[*]}" -- "$@"
) || exit
eval "set -- $parsed_opts"
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  o=$1; shift
  case $o in
    (--) break;;
    (--*)
      o=${o#--}
      if ((${opt_spec[$o]+1})); then # opt without argument
        eval "${opt_spec[$o]}=true"
      else
        o=$o:
        case "${opt_spec[$o]}" in
          (*'()') eval "${opt_spec[$o]%??}+=(\"\$1\")";;
          (*) eval "${opt_spec[$o]}=\$1"
        esac
        shift
      fi
  esac
done
echo "var1: ${var1[@]}"
```

That way, you can call your script as:

```
my-script --opt1=foo --opt2 bar --opt4 -- whatever
```

And getopt will do the hard work of parsing it, handling `--` and abbreviations for you.

Alternatively, you could rely on the type of the variable instead of specifying it in your `$opt_spec` associative array definition:

```
declare -A opt_spec
var1=() var2=() var4=false
unset var3
opt_spec=(
  [opt1:]=var1   # opt with argument
  [opt2:]=var2   # ditto
  [opt3:]=var3   # ditto
  [opt4]=var4    # boolean opt without argument
)
parsed_opts=$(
  IFS=,
  getopt -o + -l "${!opt_spec[*]}" -- "$@"
) || exit
eval "set -- $parsed_opts"
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  o=$1; shift
  case $o in
    (--) break;;
    (--*)
      o=${o#--}
      if ((${opt_spec[$o]+1})); then # opt without argument
        eval "${opt_spec[$o]}=true"
      else
        o=$o:
        case $(declare -p "${opt_spec[$o]}" 2> /dev/null) in
          ("declare -a"*) eval "${opt_spec[$o]}+=(\"\$1\")";;
          (*) eval "${opt_spec[$o]}=\$1"
        esac
        shift
      fi
  esac
done
echo "var1: ${var1[@]}"
```

You can add short options like:

```
declare -A long_opt_spec short_opt_spec
var1=() var2=() var4=false
unset var3
long_opt_spec=(
  [opt1:]=var1   # opt with argument
  [opt2:]=var2   # ditto
  [opt3:]=var3   # ditto
  [opt4]=var4    # boolean opt without argument
)
short_opt_spec=(
  [a:]=var1
  [b:]=var2
  [c]=var3
  [d]=var4
)
parsed_opts=$(
  IFS=; short_opts="${!short_opt_spec[*]}"
  IFS=,
  getopt -o "+$short_opts" -l "${!long_opt_spec[*]}" -- "$@"
) || exit
eval "set -- $parsed_opts"
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  o=$1; shift
  case $o in
    (--) break;;
    (--*)
      o=${o#--}
      if ((${long_opt_spec[$o]+1})); then # opt without argument
        eval "${long_opt_spec[$o]}=true"
      else
        o=$o:
        case $(declare -p "${long_opt_spec[$o]}" 2> /dev/null) in
          ("declare -a"*) eval "${long_opt_spec[$o]}+=(\"\$1\")";;
          (*) eval "${long_opt_spec[$o]}=\$1"
        esac
        shift
      fi;;
    (-*)
      o=${o#-}
      if ((${short_opt_spec[$o]+1})); then # opt without argument
        eval "${short_opt_spec[$o]}=true"
      else
        o=$o:
        case $(declare -p "${short_opt_spec[$o]}" 2> /dev/null) in
          ("declare -a"*) eval "${short_opt_spec[$o]}+=(\"\$1\")";;
          (*) eval "${short_opt_spec[$o]}=\$1"
        esac
        shift
      fi
  esac
done
echo "var1: ${var1[@]}"
```

Comment: Hi @Stéphane , thanks for your effort. Really amazing :)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you take a look at my [General Shell Script GitHub: utility_functions.sh](https://github.com/Silvarion/generic-shell-script/blob/master/utility_functions.sh). There you will see a function called **getArgs**. It's designed for associating options and values.

I'm pasting here the function only, but it depends on a couple more functions inside that script

```
##########################
#
#   Function name: getArgs
#
#   Description:
#       This function provides the getopts functionality
#   while allowing the use of long operations and list of parameters.
#   in the case of a list of arguments for only one option, this list
#   will be returned as a single-space-separated list in one single string.
#
#   Pre-reqs:
#       None
#
#   Output:
#       GA_OPTION variable will hold the current option
#       GA_VALUE variable will hold the value (or list of values) associated
#           with the current option
#   
#   Usage:
#       You have to source the function in order to be able to access the GA_OPTIONS
#   and GA_VALUES variables
#       . getArgs $*
#
####################
function getArgs {

    # Variables to return the values out of the function
    typeset -a GA_OPTIONS
    typeset -a GA_VALUES

    # Checking for number of arguments
    if [[ -z $1 ]]
    then
        msgPrint -warning "No arguments found"
        msgPrint -info "Please call this function as follows: . getArgs \$*"
        exit 0
    fi

    # Grab the dash
    dash=$(echo $1 | grep "-")
    # Looking for short (-) or long (--) options
    isOption=$(expr index "$dash" "-")
    # Initialize the counter
    counter=0
    # Loop while there are arguments left
    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
    do
        if [[ $dash && $isOption -eq 1 ]]
        then
            (( counter+=1 ))
            GA_OPTIONS[$counter]=$1
            shift
        else
            if [[ -z ${GA_VALUES[$counter]} ]]
            then
                GA_VALUES[$counter]=$1
            else
                GA_VALUES[$counter]="${GA_VALUES[$counter]} $1"
            fi
            shift
        fi
        dash=$(echo $1 | grep "-")
        isOption=$(expr index "$dash" "-")
    done
    # Make the variables available to the main algorithm
    export GA_OPTIONS
    export GA_VALUES

    msgPrint -debug "Please check the GA_OPTIONS and GA_VALUES arrays for options and arguments"
    # Exit with success
    return 0
}
```

As you see, this particular function will export GA_OPTIONS and GA_VALUES. Only condition for this is that the values must be a space-separated list after the option.

You would call the script as
./tool --var1 2 3 4 5 --var2="6" --var3="7"

Or just use similar logic to accommodate your preferences.

Comment: `getArgs $*` would pass the result of the split+glob operator applied to the list of positional parameters to getArgs,  it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `echo $1 | grep -`, Would return the lines in the output of `echo $1` (again $1 being subject to split+glob, and echo expanding sequences) that contain a dash.